# A tag target="_blank" in safari ios history start from 2?

Tags: html, mobile-safari

Why A tag target="_blank" in safari ios history start from 2?
and how to Fix start with 1?

```
<a href='example.com' target='_blank'>click me</a>
```

Comment: how is this question related to `ios`